# IntelliJ - Code formatting, spaces before one liner method braces

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, code-formatting

I like to keep simple methods, like getters and setter, on a single line. 
In order to achive it, I need to use `CTRL+J` (join lines), it works good, but it doesn't add a space between the semicolon and the left curly brace.

**Actual situation**

```
public String getAddress()  { return address;} <--Missing space
```

**Expected result**

```
public String getAddress()  { return address; }
```

I'm playing with the code style rules, but nothing seems to work.

It would be nice to place single statement methods on a single line automatically, avoiding the need of using `CTRL+J` on each method.

**Wrong**

```
public String concatAddress() { String x = "abcdefghi"; return address + x; }
```

**Good**

```
public String concatAddress() {
    String x = "abcdefghi";
    return address + x;
}
```

With both "problems" solved, the auto-formatting would put simple methods on one single line, and format them correctly, while formatting multi-line methods as usual.

I don't understan why in the "Spaces" tab, there are the "Before Left Brace" settings, while there's no "x Right Brace" at all.

Comment: There is a related request you can vote for: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111802.

Comment: So it's really not configured yet... I though I was missing a special setting! ... Thanks, I've replied to the issue

Answer (score 1):

The two settings you want to enable in Intellij for this behaviour are under code styles and are:

- Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Spaces > Within: Code Braces
- Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Wrapping and Braces: Simple methods one line

This behaviour seems to have changed in a recent version of IntelliJ, as my template stopped working properly without having the Within: Code Braces part enabled (and it seems like something must have turned off my Simple Methods one line setting, since that was in my IDE setup docs for myself and wasn't turned on anymore after an update).

Comment: Hi, I've just checked in phpStorm (I'm not using Java now), the feature has not been implemented yet in php, java/typescript. So it looks like it's implemented only in Java by your answer... :/